# SurfaceView Example

Tags: java, android, canvas, surfaceview, surfaceholder

So I've spent about two days trying to get a working `SurfaceView`. Tutorials I am following online aren't working even when followed to the letter. I normally get an entirely black screen.

In order to help teach myself how it works I need a working `SurfaceView` program.

I'm looking for a program that has the `SurfaceView` generated in a separate class. I would be very grateful if someone is able to post full code (XML and Java) for a `SurfaceView` program that simply turns the entire screen Red or White.

Thank you for any help!

(Any explanations along with the code would be amazing!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this link

[Ansroid SurfaceView Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/surfaceview/android-surfaceview-example/)

I followed this tutorial example. It works fine.

### Edit

Simple Code for `SurfaceView`

**Layout xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Activity Code**

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity{


  SurfaceView surfaceView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    //Method for making the activity full screen
    //With SurfaceView
    makeItFullScreen();
  }
  
  private void makeItFullScreen(){
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    //Changing SurfaceView background color
    surfaceView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams videoLayoutParams = surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
    videoLayoutParams.width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    videoLayoutParams.height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams videoParams = surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
    videoParams.width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    videoParams.height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
  }

}
```

### Edit2

If you use custom SurfaceView xml will be like this..

```xml
<customClassPackageName.CustomSurfaceViewClassName
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Code inside Activity

```
  .......
  customClassPackageName.CustomSurfaceViewClassName surfaceView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    surfaceView = (customClassPackageName.CustomSurfaceViewClassName) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    .......
```

Comment: I have been through that example along with too many others. I am really just looking for some code that another user can confirm works and is extremely basic (like turning the screen red or white). I will be using this sample to learn from.

Comment: Thank you, I have marked this as the answer as it demonstrates the techniques I was looking for an worked. Another thing that I am very curios about is are you able to not define a SurfaceView in the XML and create/ manipulate a SurfaceView from another Java class within the project?

Comment: yes you can. see this  http://android-er.blogspot.com/2014/03/simple-surfaceview-example.html

Comment: Thank you for the help however when I use that website it crashes the application. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Do you check log?  What is  the exception?

Comment: 1-22 16:40:52.104 9548-9548/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.Frenchie.SurfaceView, PID: 9548
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Frenchie.SurfaceView/com.Frenchie.SurfaceView.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.androidsurfaceview.MySurfaceView

Comment: Sorry to keep nagging I still cant seem to get that working... In this instance what would be the customClassPackageName  and customeSurfaceViewClassName. Sorry to be such a pain with this all your comments are appreciated!

Comment: Every class must under a package right? so that name is customClassPackageName. you will get it top of the class. like com.frenchie.surfacev​iew. and then add the Class name like com.frenchie.surfacev​iew.MySurfaceView.

Comment: 1-23 12:40:21.286 7926-7926/com.Frenchie.SurfaceView E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.Frenchie.SurfaceView, PID: 7926
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Frenchie.SurfaceView/com.Frenchie.SurfaceView.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.example.androidsurfaceview.MySurfaceView

Comment: I thought that was what you meant I was just checking, the error for this is above as it didnt work :/

Answer (score 6):

**SurfaceView**

In Android, all simple layout views are all drawn on the same GUI thread which is also used for all user interaction. So if we need to update GUI rapidly or if the rendering takes too much time and affects user experience then we should use SurfaceView.

The Android SurfaceView provides a dedicated drawing surface embedded inside of a view hierarchy. You can control the format of this surface, however, the SurfaceView takes care of placing the surface at the correct location on the screen.

Check this [sample](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/surfaceview/android-surfaceview-example/)

Comment: Thank you for the information, I have followed the sample previously and didn't receive any success, I am really looking for something more simple.